# BigQuery Error getting metadata for external code resource

Tags: google-bigquery, udf

I am getting this error "Error getting metadata for external code resource" on BigQuery, and it references the file where a GCS-residing UDF is in. The same query with the same code as an inline UDF works. However, when I reference it on GCS it fails.
What does this error mean? 
And, why is it failing?

Answer (score 1):

And the answer was: we had mis-typed the name of the file containing the UDF. Not a particularly helpful error message though (and no reference to what it means in the BQ docs...)

Comment: The issue is that we can't really determine whether the file is not there, or if you've specified a resource you don't have access to.  I can add a note to the error message to "verify you have provided the correct path" or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the report!  We will be adding some details to the error message when we can't access the specified GCS resource : "please verify you have provided a valid path and/or that you have access to the resource".

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue.

Had to make the service account running the query a GCS `Storage Object Viewer` on the bucket that contains the code for the UDF (User Defined Function).